# CIFilter inputIntensity slider for big images

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cifilter

I have implemented `NSSlider` for `CIFilter inputIntensity` adjustment. Its working. But when I try to adjust `CIFilter` intensity for big image it is laggy. Slider is set to be `continuous`, because I need user to be able see effect while moving slider. And when slider is being moved my app starts to lag a lot. Is there any possible solution to make it without lag? Because I saw many apps which has this feature and are working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example coalesce updates, thus not updating the filter parameter for every single event fired by the slider but only every 200ms for example.

If you have a hires image, alternatively display filter changes on a low resolution image displayed above the high resolution one and update the large images when slider dragging ends.